# Python find device disk

Tags: python, volume

hi im trying to find the devce disk from the volume name for eg.

i enter as "Shared" as volume name

and the return is what disk it is

i currently have the following to unmount a flash card. i need the what disk it is so that i can DD an image to it.

```
 #!/bin/py

import os
import subprocess

# enter flash card name
cardName = raw_input('Enter your name of Card: ')

# unmount flash card
subprocess.call(['sudo' ,'umount', '/Volumes/' + cardName])
```

tryong this on OSX at the moment but idealy would like it universal, or at least able to run on Rasbian but thats a nice to have feature

Comment: What is a volume name?

Comment: Will the device be mounted anywhere, and if so, where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot reliably convert a volume label (that doesn't necessary exist at all) to the OS device name, even more so in a cross-platform way.

Comment: i cant believe it cant be done! with the cmd os.system('df -k /Volumes/Untitled') it returns infomation including the disk location, now i just need to filter it down some how

Comment: @Spriggsy it's OS-specific and will show only mounted devices.

Comment: thanks for the info, i guess that just means putting in a check to see which OS im running at the start,ill accept this as the answer for all the help youve givern. however ive gotten it working with

"df '/Volumes/' + cardName | awk '{ print $1 }' | tail -n 1"

Answer (score 0):

You can find device disk by volume name like this.

```
DISK_BY_LABEL = '/dev/disk/by-label/'
filename = DISK_BY_LABEL + VolumeName
devfile = DISK_BY_LABEL + os.readlink(filename)
```

Note: /dev/disk/by-label directory create by udev daemon.

Comment: To be on safe side, I think you should use `os.path.join` instead of `+` to concatenate the strings.